# how to change the order of the filters

Tags: angularjs

I was given some help on this already but I am really stuck on another part. right now the filters work in this order. the salary filter must be selected before the job title or the input filters will work. I am looking to have it setup so there is no specific order has to be used. is this possible? if not could the order change to were the input field was first and then the job title and then the salary? I tried some different ways of doing it but i could not get it to work. thank you

http://plnkr.co/edit/Kq3S51NMsgPt14sidBdo?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your filter function isn't robust against the salary being undefined.

`parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN`. Even `infinity >= NaN` is false.

You should change your filter to this instead:

```
$scope.salaryFilter = function (min) {
  return parseInt(min.salaryMin) >= parseInt($scope.salary_Min || 0) ;
};
```

The `|| 0` addition will replace the minimum salary with zero if it is a falsy value (i.e. null or undefined.)